# Read/Write to a file does not write to the output

Tags: java, file-io, outputstream, printwriter

I am writing a program that reads input from one file, then the program would formate the data and write it to a different file.

Input file:

> Christopher kardaras,10 N Brainard,Naperville,IL,60566 George
>   Washington,30 W Jackson,Chicago,IL,60060

Output file:

> Christopher kardaras 10 N Brainard Naperville, IL 60566
>
> George Washington 30 W Jackson Chicago, IL 60060

when I run the code the output does not show in the output file, the following is my code.

```
    //open input, output files
    FileReader freader = new FileReader("AddressData.txt");
    BufferedReader inFile = new BufferedReader(freader);

    FileWriter fwriter=new FileWriter("FormattedData.text");
    PrintWriter outFile= new PrintWriter (fwriter);

    //process data - get a line, separate into fields, then print
    //address label to the output file

    line= inFile.readLine();
    while (line != null)
    {
        //Create a new scanner, use comma as field separator
        Scanner s = new Scanner(line).useDelimiter(",");

        // SOME CODE OMITTED HERE FOR BREVITY
        out.printf(...);

        //get the next line. read failure (EOF) will exit the loop
        line = inFile.readLine();
    }

    //clean up
    inFile.close();
    outFile.close();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [flushing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html#flush%28%29) the outFile before closing it.

```
outFile.flush();
```

You can also use the [alternative PrintWriter constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html#PrintWriter%28java.io.OutputStream,%20boolean%29) that takes care of that for you:

```
public PrintWriter(OutputStream out, boolean autoFlush)
```

Comment: When writing... first flush the contents and finally close! :)